# Style field not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

Consider the following code:

```
<p
  key={element.text}
  className={element.complete ? "strike" : ""}
  style={{
           borderLeft: `2px solid ${getColor(element)}`,
           color: days < 0 ? "#d9534f" : "whitesmoke",
        }}
 >
```

and the function `getColor`:

```
const getColor = (e) => {
    props.sortedArray.map((element) => {
      if (e.project === element.name) {
        console.log(element.color);
        return element.color;
      }
    });
```

The object `e` :

```
{
complete: false
deadline: Tue Mar 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
priority: "high"
project: "Gravity"
text: "Finish this page"
user: ""
}
```

and the object `element`:

```
{
color: "#EADBDF"
deadline: Sat Apr 30 2022 21:33:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
description: "oshofchsfhsckjscjksjdchs"
name: "Gravity"
subject: "em"
}
```

when i `console.log(element.color)` it shows the expected value(a hex color), but for some reason the style (`borderLeft`) isnt being rendered. I cant seem to figure out why. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're expecting
`const getColor = (e) =>`  e object in `getColor()` function, but you providing there an `element` object.

---

Edit:
You do not return the value from `getColor()` function, that's why the console.log shows you the right value but doesn't return it.

Just simply add a return statement.

```js
const getColor = (e) => {
   return props.sortedArray.map((element) => {
      if (e.project === element.name) {
        console.log(element.color);
        return element.color;
      }
    });
```

or skip parentasis, and return it like that:

```js
const getColor = (e) => props.sortedArray.map((element) => {
      if (e.project === element.name) {
        console.log(element.color);
        return element.color;
      }
    });
```

Comment: No, thats alright cause up until the console.log() the behavior is exactly as expected

Comment: Okay, i see you just do not return the value from `getColor()` function, there is no return statement

Comment: I didnt quite get you. there is a return statement after the console.log() right?

Comment: Yes but this return statement is for `map()` function. You have to return your map() result. Look at edited answer.

Comment: tried both the methods mentioned, no change

Answer (score 0):

```
const getColor = (e) => {
    let color = "";
    props.sortedArray.map((element) => {
      if (e.project === element.name) {
        color = element.color;
        return element.color;
      }
    });
    return color;
  };
```

Comment: First of all, do not answer your questions. Then you do not need a `let`. Just return the `props.sortedArray.map()` from your `getColor()` function.

Comment: i tried doing that like mentioned in the other answer, didn't work. tried this and it worked

Comment: @programmer Self-answered questions are perfectly fine. Please don't give bad advice.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.